# Flyback converter with dual outputs (12V / 5V)

Tags: flyback, ac-dc

I came across the following flyback converter circuit, which has a dual output (12V and 5V), but I am unable to figure out why the secondary windings are connected in series.

Based on the datasheet of the transformer (750343773 - Würth), the secondary windings should produce (considering Vin ~ 85VDC) 13.52V (12V + V(D21)) and 5.79V (5V + V(D22)) respectively, which would make sense if they were sharing the same ground instead of being connected in series. Furthemore, the feedback network formed by the TL431, R26, R25 and R25A apparently is set to an output voltage of 18.56V and 8.72V respectively. Can anyone explain how the 12V and 5V can be achieved with this configuration?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same datasheet as I am? The two secondaries are tied together internally to the transformer (see the pin numbering in the schematic you supplied) and their ratios are appropriate for 5V/12V. https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/750343773.pdf

Comment: This datasheet is new to me and its wiring matches the one shown in the schematic. Thanks for that. The feedback network though seems to be configured for a different voltage. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Show your calcs for the input voltage to the TL431.

Comment: According to the shut regulator datasheet, the cathode will sink any current in order to keep its voltage equal to
$$
V_{ka} = V_{ref}  (1 + \frac{R_1} {R_2}) + I_{ref} \cdot  R_1 
$$
$$
V_{ka}@12V = 2.495V \cdot  (1 + \frac{16k\Omega} {2k5\Omega}) + 2\mu A \cdot 16k\Omega = 18.495V
$$
$$
V_{ka}@5V = 2.495V \cdot  (1 + \frac{6k2\Omega} {2k5\Omega}) + 2\mu A \cdot 6k2\Omega = 8.695V
$$
In this case since both lines are connected in parallel to the feedback network in a OR-ish configuration, the feedback will respond to the voltage which first exceeds the threshold (18.49V or 8.69V ).

Comment: @vtolentino,  no that's what's known as a summing junction the voltages will both contribute simultaneously. so he limits are lower.

Comment: assume 2.5V across R26 (it's easier than assuming 2.495V and only 0.2% off) some of the 1mA current in R26 comes through R25 and some through R25A , both at the same time.  with 12V at the top of R25 and 2.5V at the bottom that 9.5V/16K which comes out a about 0.6mA with 5V on the top of R25A   2.5/6.2K gives about 0.4mA so It all makes sense how it is. deriving the set point from the resistors is harder, and it's probably easier to just simulate the circuit.

Comment: @Jasen Brilliant! It makes sense now. My approach towards it was indeed misleading.

Comment: I came up with the following equation for calculating \$ V_{ref}\$ as a function of the supply voltages and resistances:
$$
V_{ref}= \frac{(V_{5V}\cdot R_{25}+V_{12V}\cdot R_{25A}-I_{ref}\cdot R_{25}\cdot R_{25A})}{R_{25}\cdot R_{25A} + R_{26}\cdot R_{25} + R_{26}\cdot R_{25A}}
$$
It seems to work fine if both voltages are properly set. I wonder what would happen if one of the outputs fails to regulate, therefore delivering less current which in turn will not turn on the optocopler.